# Bootstrap.min.js does not work dropdown menu after use $('body').load(currentURL)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

First, my master page with below js, it's worked 100% no errors on any webform.aspx if I postback (f5):

```
<script src="../../Content/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.2 JS -->
<script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Admin Custom Js by Hoang -->
<script src="../../Action/Admin/AdminRV.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Content/js/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="../../Content/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- SlimScroll 1.3.0 -->
<script src="../../Content/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Content/js/docs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Action/Admin/SiteMap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, user menu dropdown will not work if I use `reloadPage`, which helps me to reload body of next page webform and keep template body or contentHeader safe. It just reloads ContentPlaceHolder of that webform I clicked.

```
function reloadPage(id) {
var state = {
    "thisIsOnPopState": true
};
var idPage = id;
var currentURL = $('a[id="' + idPage + '"]').attr('role');
history.pushState(state, null, currentURL);
$('body').load(currentURL);}
```

How do I fix the event click dropdown from bootstrap.min.js when I reload the page?

Comment: I think we need markup here please

Comment: i don't understand ?

Comment: Could you provide with the relevant markup (wich  HTML user interacts with and wich event handlers  invoked?